# jquery ui button crashes on click in IE8(only)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, crash, uibutton

i am using jquery ui button with following HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4

/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.save,.cancel').button();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ol><li>
<div> 
<a class="save">Save</a>
<a class="cancel">cancel</a>
</div>
</li></ol>
</body>
</html>
```

when click save or cancel IE8(not even ie7) crashes with following error

```
res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm#
```

However it works fine with following html

```
<div> 
<a class="save">Save</a>
<a class="cancel">cancel</a>
</div>
```

or

```
<ol><li>
<a class="save">Save</a>
<a class="cancel">cancel</a>
</li></ol>
```

i,m testing it in window7,
going crazy over it ,any help is appreciated,Thanks

**update:**
This Fixes it

```
<ol><li>
<div style="display:inline-block;" >
<a class="save" href="#" onclick="return false;" >Save</a>
<a class="cancel" href="#" onclick="return false;" >cancel</a>
</div>
</li></ol>
```

Moral of the Story:IE's r piece of crap

Comment: just for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/dittodhole/yA9G5/1/ - does this page cause your ie to crash?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, the asker has setup an standalone page. the problem should be re-produced on HTML page. it seems to work in jsfiddle, but when I tried the HTML page, my IE8 also got crashed.

Comment: @tusar i know :) but a globally available fiddle is sometimes nice :) maybe it's connected to your local html page - what if you upload the whole setup, and not try it via `localhost`... sometimes that causes headaches ... .)

Comment: Yeah,earlier i tried to make a jsfiddle for it ,but it doesnt  throw that problem,so i wrote whole html,i,m testing on localhost,http://jsfiddle.net/dittodhole/yA9G5/1/ doesnt throw error

Comment: well, then it may be localhost, which causes your problem - ever uploaded your setup to a webserver and tested it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a div surrounding your  links?

I think here you should try to cancel the click from HTML. also, put a href="" or href="#" tag. 
To cancel the click, use

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="save"></a>
```

Might fix the problem.

Comment: To place button in particular html format is requirement and onclick="return false;" doesnt fix it

Comment: So... eventually, why won't you try to use a <div class="save"> and use your same code of $(".save").button(); ? Catching a click event from jQuery might help fixing it. Otherwise it's a JS problem then.

Comment: Also, did you define your classes .save{} and .cancel{} in your css? If empty, it could potentially rise an issue.

Comment: tried setting class on div or defining css-styling ,stil its No

Comment: CSS does not affect JavaScript at all... (let's ignore some ie-specific things such as `behaviour`)

Comment: So finally, href + onclick + container as inline-block fixed your issue? Very interesting.